# Disable OPTIONS header using backbone.js to call a REST api

Tags: performance, rest, backbone.js

I realized that every call to my REST api, backbone.js sends a OPTIONS call first and then it sends the verb that I wanted (POST, GET, etc...). Is there a way to disable this first call (OPTIONS) ? Or at least make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ajax request calls with OPTIONS method first, it means that your REST api is on another domain (or on another sub-domain of your domain). This is a default behavior in jQuery XHR requests (for now BB sync uses jQuery for ajax requests). You can't make it faster (i think it just retrieves headers, so it should be really fast) and you can't disable it.

The only (and poor) alternative is making JSONP GET requests.